# C&C/Boxer Source Code

Tags: computational-linguistics, semantics, software, formal-semantics

I’ve been trying to find C&C tools and Boxer online and found this link in many places (http://svn.ask.it.usyd.edu.au/trac/candc) but the link does not work for me. Is there another place to find these tools?

I did see that you have the source code available here (https://github.com/valeriobasile/learningbyreading/tree/master/ext/candc), and I tried to install it (on OS X 10.12) but it gave me an error.

Also, are there other wide-coverage semantic parsers out there that would be good alternatives? Or is this considered the state-of-the-art semantic parser? I’m hoping that I will be able to use these tools for my research project involving translation of laws to formal representation.

Answer (score 1):

The parser you linked to has been rewritten in Java and improved. The latest software can be downloaded from [Stephen Clark's C&C tools page](https://sites.google.com/site/stephenclark609/resources). The old C++ version can be downloaded from there too, which comes with Boxer.

As for state-of-the-art tools, I can't recommend anything, but [SIGPARSE](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sigparse/) and [SIGSEM](http://www.sigsem.org/w/)  are good starting points to find them.